# iPad 2 company installed monitoring malware

Tags: ios, privacy, malware, mobile-device-management

A company I used to work for installed tracking malware on my iPad 2. It monitors my emails, Facebook, changes my passwords, etc. I did a complete reset at an Apple Store, it is still there. The Apple tech support told me I would have to go back to the company to have it removed? My wife works there, and it will create problems for her. Any suggestions?

Comment: You don't provide many informations. How do you know it is still there? Is it an App on your home screen? Is it a "Profile"?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what speficially monitors your email? Is it sent trough a VPN/proxy? What specific passwords get changed? If you erase all settings and content - there are no controls left. Did you restore a backup or re-join corporate email/MDM control?

Answer (score 3):

Apple allows end users to remove any MDM profiles that could be seen as Malware if you didn't agree to enroll the device in the first place.

1. Apple ensures pretty well that a company cannot push these settings to any device except ones they strictly own.
2. If you enroll a BYOD iPad into their MDM - you are prompted to agree to enroll the device and you can inspect what sort of data collection and control you are yielding to the company.
3. At any time, you can remove the restrictions/monitoring - but you will then lose the Apps that are provisioned from the company, company data that is stored in company apps as well as loss of email accounts. This removal is surgical - only the items that "belong" to the company get deleted - all content remains unless it came in after the profile and under the profile's control.
4. If you don't trust the surgical remove option - power off the device and restore it from iTunes.

I wouldn't call any of this malware since it was designed in by Apple and intended to be used in the way it is used. Hopefully you weren't surprised by what you agreed to when you enrolled the device or handed it over to IT. If you received it from IT - you may have missed all the prompts.

Best of luck - and you'll know to carefully inspect all profiles going forward so you've comfortable with the control you cede to anyone else running a MDM.

Answer (score 2):

Mobile Device Management software can be installed by a company and is often part of an arrangement to allow work-related information on the device (such as work email or applications). They are specifically designed to prevent someone to remove the policy - once the device comes back online, typically the policy will reattach itself and/or you will receive incessant warnings about the policy having been removed which can kill a device should the company configure it that way.

In short, **you will need** to contact the company to have them remove the profile from the device (they should be able to do this from their end). Otherwise, you will have to get another device or lose access to the functions that made the policy required in the first place.

Comment: I will give it a shot! Be wary working in Mexico !

Comment: That is exactly what they did, giving us a co. E-mail account, with our personal E-mail acc. As "backup" also sales apps, using Facebook I noticed it going through the co. Sales app. Thank You!